# Is it possible to upgrade the drive in a Time Capsule?

Tags: time-capsule

The Time Capsule has limited space, and the price difference from 2TB to 3TB is absurd: another $200 for a single additional terabyte.  (I'm sure they'll increase that with the next round of Time Capsules, whenever they release those, but I don't know when that'll be, and I'd rather vote with my wallet to tell Apple their Time Capsule is overpriced.)

So how hard would it be to crack open a Time Capsule and upgrade the drive to something a little larger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By all means - vote with your wallet. It's trivial for a trained technician to replace the hard drive on a Time Capsule. Rather than put the rubber covering back on the base, you can use [inexpensive silicone bumpers](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10594) to raise the capsule up from it's shelf. Most feel iFixit has decent [repair guides](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Replacing-Apple-Time-Capsule-HDD/2750/1) if you care to DIY.